# Is a polyhedron an affline manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, linear-programming

I was reading the definition of an affine manifold (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Affine_manifold)
and was wondering if a polyhedron is an affine manifold. Could you also provide any hints to the proof or to a reliable source. Thanks !

Comment: From the definition provided, an affine manifold does not have boundary. So if by polyhedron you include the boundary, then it is not affine. If the boundary is not included, then it is affine, as all open set in the Euclidean spaces are affine.

Comment: Maybe I'm way out of my depth here, but it seems to me that the [tag:linear-programming] tag is not at all relevant... Am I correct? And [tag:linear-algebra] seems to be a huge stretch too.

Comment: Affine manifolds admitting polyhedral decompositions are a hot topic in mirror symmetry - see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211094).

Comment: @John I've always seen polyhedra defined as surfaces, in which case they are without boundary: even more, convex polyhedra are homeomorphic to $S^2$. Do you by chance include the interior, too, in your definition?

Comment: @A.P. If you are thinking about surface (those related to Euler characteristic?), it refers, as you said, only to the "boundary". But it seems that the term more commonly are referring to the solid figure. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron ). Anyway, yes, I am including the interior.

Comment: @John The Wikipedia page you linked isn't clear on the frequency of the use of the different definitions. The relevant [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhedron.html) is a bit more clear on the context in which the two definitions are used.

Comment: @A.P. Now I am confused... In which context will the term refers to the surfaces?

Comment: @john @ A.P. The polyhedron I am referring to is defined by linear equalities and inequalities. It includes the interior as well. So if I were to exclude the equalities, the remaining region would be an affline manifold?

Comment: If by "exclude the equalities" you mean exclude the boundary, then my very first comment still holds. However, I doubt if this is really what you want. In what context are you faced with this definition? @user2535015

Comment: @John The only moment where I encountered polyhedra in my formal education was when I was taught about symmetry groups. In that context they were defined as a collection of polygons joined at the edges (with some extra condition).

Comment: I would like to check for strong duality for a quadratic program subject to quadratic constraints over an affline manifold. I also have linear constraints and was wondering if the linear constraints (which form a polyhedra) form a affline manifold.